# How to secure a Django template to get its values (HTML and Javascript) altered by inspect element feature of web browser?

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I am working on a Django website where I need to display some services of a company and user can select type of the services from radio buttons given on the page. Price for that different type of services is getting fetched from the database. As soon the user select the radio button for any type of service, the price of that service is copied to a HTML label using javascript also sum of the total selected services is calculated through javascript and shown to different label called total. Now what I want to do is, on click of a button I need to store the user selection and Total payable amount to a session back in the view. I thought to do it via ajax call using javascript but if the user alters/change the value of all those labels which are being calculated on client side, using inspect element feature than the ajax call will send the modified data which and hence it seems to be insecure method. So could anyone please guide me how can I deal with this problem.

Below is the code of my tmeplate:

```
<table class="LeftOffers">
    <tr><th style="width:450px;">Packages</th><th>Small</th><th>Medium</th><th>Large</th></tr>
    {%for package in packages%}
        <tr><td><label id="package{{forloop.counter}}">{{package.PackageName}}</label><br>{{package.PackageDesc}}</td>
        <td> <label><input name="package{{forloop.counter}}" id="small" value="{{package.SmallPrice}}" onchange="updateTotal(name)" type="radio">Rs {{package.SmallPrice}}</label></td>
        <td> <label><input name="package{{forloop.counter}}" id="med" value="{{package.MedPrice}}" onchange="updateTotal(name)" type="radio">Rs {{package.MedPrice}}</label></td>
        <td> <label><input name="package{{forloop.counter}}" id="large" value="{{package.LargePrice}}" onchange="updateTotal(name)" type="radio">Rs {{package.LargePrice}}</label></td>
    </tr>
    {%endfor%}
</table>
```

Here services are the packages and small, medium and large are different types of the packages.

Below is the Javascript used to show the price of selected items on some labels and to calculate the total payable amount:

```
function updateTotal(names) {
    pkgname = document.getElementById(names).innerHTML;
    rowlbl = "row_"+names;
    namelbl = "label_"+names;
    prclbl = "optionsPrice_"+names;
    btnid = "button_"+names;
    document.getElementById(rowlbl).style.display='inline';
    document.getElementById(btnid).style.display='inline';
    document.getElementById(namelbl).innerHTML = pkgname;
    document.getElementById(prclbl).innerHTML = "Rs "+ $("input[name="+names+"]:checked").val();
    totalPrice=0;
    {% for package in packages %}

        lblname = "optionsPrice_package{{forloop.counter}}";
        lblprc = document.getElementById(lblname).innerHTML;
        if (lblprc != ""){
            lblprc = lblprc.replace("Rs ","");
        } else{
            lblprc = "0";
        }
        totalPrice = totalPrice + parseInt(lblprc); 
    {% endfor %}
document.getElementById('totalPrice').innerHTML = "Rs " + totalPrice.toString();
}
```

Please let me know if I am missing anything here.

Also attaching the screenshot of my page for reference:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: i dont understand what you want

Comment: I want to store the detail of packages selected by user and the total payable amount in a session back in the views, on click of "Proceed to Checkout button". Now, as far my logic this can be done using ajax call but I am afraid abiut its security. Like what if some one alters the price of Total Amount using "Inspect Element" feature and than click on the button? I believe, the ajax call will send the modified Total Payable amount to the server and I want to prevent the same. Could you suggest any alternative for this.

Comment: do NOT save money amounts and this kind of important data in session! save better in your db and yes, ajax is not a professional way for this

Comment: Thanks Doniyor, Do you have any better way to do this in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic example of the [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/); your chosen solution, storing calculated data in fields, is subject to a security issue, so you ask how that can be prevented, rather than realising this solution is not suitable.

You should not be sending the total from your form at all. Feel free to calculate it in JS to show to the user, but don't send it. You are already posting the details of the selected packages to the backend; use *that* data, rather than the posted total, to calculate the actual amount payable.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. You are the savior for every Python/Django beginner in this community.